# Batch Adding Compile Error

Tags: batch

I'm trying to create a list from a custom object (InvoiceAccount) and with a key of AccountID, get all the related Contacts and insert fields from both of them into another Custom object (InvoiceAccountContact).  I'm getting this compiling error. Any thoughts?

[image]

```
    global class InvoiceAccountContactBatch implements Database.Batchable<InvoiceAccount__c> {

    global InvoiceAccountContactBatch(){}

    global List<InvoiceAccount__c> start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
      return [Select ID, Name, OwnerID, Client_Code__c, Client_Type__c, Sugar_ID__c, QB_Customer_Reference__c From InvoiceAccount__c
//    WHERE Client_Code__c !=''
    ORDER BY Name];
//Limit 250
 //condition to prevent dupe records.. may be by time frame?];
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<InvoiceAccount__c> scope) {
       List<InvoiceAccount__c> lstInvoiceAccount = new List<InvoiceAccount__c>();
       for(Account lstInvoiceAccount_Single : scope){

        //system.debug(lstInvoiceAccount_Single);
        //system.debug(lstInvoiceAccount_Single.Id + ' -> ' + lstInvoiceAccount_Single.Name);
        //system.debug(''); 

    // Set Variables for Insert

    // InvoiceAccount
    String var_Id = lstInvoiceAccount_Single.Id;
    String var_Name = lstInvoiceAccount_Single.Name;
    String var_OwnerID = lstInvoiceAccount_Single.OwnerID;
    String var_Sugar_ID = lstInvoiceAccount_Single.Sugar_ID__c;
    String var_Client_Code = lstInvoiceAccount_Single.Client_Code__c;
    String var_Client_Status = lstInvoiceAccount_Single.Client_Status__c;
    String var_Client_Type = lstInvoiceAccount_Single.Client_Type__c;
    String var_QB_Customer_Reference = lstInvoiceAccount_Single.QB_Customer_Reference__c;

    // Contract/Contract Split
    String var_Contract_Id = '';
    String var_Finance_Charge = '';        // Not needed
    Decimal var_Audit_Savings_Split;

    Decimal var_Contract_Split;
    Date var_Split_End_Date;
    Date var_Split_Start_Date;

    // Carrier
    // String var_DHL = '';
    // String var_DHL_Download_File = '';
    // String var_DHL_Status = '';
    // String var_DHL_Audit = false;
    // String var_DHL_= false;
    Boolean var_FedEx = false;
    String var_FedEx_Download_File = '';
    String var_FedEx_Status = '';
    Boolean var_FedEx_Audit = false;
    Boolean var_FedEx_CAN = false;

    // String var_GSO = '';
    // String var_GSO_Download_File = '';
    // String var_GSO_Status = '';
    // String var_GSO_Audit = false;
    // String var_GSO_CAN = false;
    // String var_Ontrac = '';
    // String var_Ontrac_Download_File = '';
    // String var_Ontrac_Status = false;
    // String var_Ontrac_Audit = false;
    // String var_Ontrac_CAN = '';
    // String var_Postal_Service = '';
    // String var_Postal_Service_Download_File = '';
    // String var_Postal_Service_Status = '';
    // String var_Postal_Service_Audit = false;
    // String var_Postal_Service_CAN = false;
    Boolean var_UPS = false;
    String var_UPS_Download_File = '';
    String var_UPS_Status = '';
    Boolean var_UPS_Audit = false;
    Boolean var_UPS_CAN = false;

    // Account Owner
    String var_NewColumn_Name = '';
    String var_NewColumn_Title = '';
    String var_NewColumn_Email = '';

    // Contact

    String var_Contact_Id = '';
    String var_Email = ''; 
    String var_Contact_Name = '';
    String var_FirstName = '';
    String var_LastName = ''; 
    String var_Contact_Sugar_ID = '';
    String var_Contact_Type = ''; 
    String var_Invoice_Type = '';

    Boolean var_Billing_Contact = false;
    Boolean var_Billing_Contact_Verified = false; 
    Boolean  var_Monthly_Savings_Report = false; 
    String var_R_T_Report_Format = '';
    Boolean  var_Recovery_Transaction_Report = false;
    String var_Report_Format = ''; 
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Contacts
  List<Contact> lstContact = [SELECT Id,Name,FirstName, LastName, Sugar_ID__c
      FROM Contact
    WHERE AccountId = :lstInvoiceAccount_Single.Id
    Limit 1
    ];

     for (Contact lstContact_Single : lstContact) {
       var_Contract_Id = lstContact[0].Id;
       var_Sugar_ID = lstContact[0].Sugar_ID__c;
        var_Contact_Name =  lstContact[0].Name;
        var_FirstName = lstContact[0].FirstName;
        var_LastName = lstContact[0].LastName; 

     lstInvoiceAccount.add(new InvoiceAccountContact__c(
               //   FullName__c = lstInvoiceAccount_Single.Name,
  Account_ID__c = lstInvoiceAccount_Single.Id,
  Account_Owner__c = lstInvoiceAccount_Single.OwnerID,
  Sugar_ID__c = lstInvoiceAccount_Single.Sugar_ID__c,
  Client_Code__c = lstInvoiceAccount_Single.Client_Code__c,
  Client_Status__c = lstInvoiceAccount_Single.Client_Status__c,
  Client_Type__c = lstInvoiceAccount_Single.Client_Type__c,
  QB_Customer_Reference__c = lstInvoiceAccount_Single.QB_Customer_Reference__c,

 // Load Contract
    //   Contract_ID__c          = var_Contract_ID, Used Only to Get Contract_Split record.
  Audit_Savings_Split__c          = var_Audit_Savings_Split,

// Contract_Split
      Contract_Split__c               = var_Contract_Split,
      Split_Start_Date__c             = var_Split_Start_Date,
      Split_End_Date__c               = var_Split_End_Date,
// Fedex
      FedEx_Audit__c                  = var_FedEx_Audit,
      FedEx_CAN__c                    = var_FedEx_CAN,
      FedEx_Download_File__c          = var_FedEx_Download_File,
      FedEx_Status__c                 = var_FedEx_Status,
      FedEx__c                        = var_FedEx,

      // UPS
      UPS_Audit__c                    = var_UPS_Audit, 
      UPS_CAN__c                      = var_UPS_CAN, 
      UPS_Download_File__c            = var_UPS_Download_File, 
      UPS_Status__c                   = var_UPS_Status, 
      UPS__c                          = var_UPS,

      // Contact
      FullName__c                    = var_Contact_Name, 
      FirstName__c                      = var_FirstName, 
      LastName__c                = var_LastName, 
      Contact_Sugar_ID__c                   = var_Contact_Sugar_ID


             )

           );
       }

       system.debug(lstInvoiceAccount);
      // insert lstInvoiceAccount;

    }


    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add a `InvoiceAccountContact__c` to a `List` of `InvoiceAccount__c`, which is not allowed. With the sole exception of a `List` of `sObject`, you can't put a record of one type into a list of another type. You need to make sure that the type of the list and the sObject you're adding to the list agree with each other.